# Java - jpanel not showing all components

Tags: java, swing, drawing, custom-component

I'm having a frustrating problem with my app. What I want (in the provided example, that is) is 3 filled rectangles like this:

```
##
 #
```

Alas, only the top-left rectangle is drawn. Here is an sscce version of my code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map map = new Map();

        Point[] poly1 = new Point[] { new Point(10, 10), new Point(40, 10), new Point(40, 40), new Point(10, 40) };
        Point[] poly2 = new Point[] { new Point(50, 10), new Point(80, 10), new Point(80, 40), new Point(50, 40) };
        Point[] poly3 = new Point[] { new Point(50, 50), new Point(80, 50), new Point(80, 80), new Point(50, 80) };

        Point[][] polys = new Point[][] { poly1, poly2, poly3 };

        ShowWindow(polys);
    }


    private static void ShowWindow(Point[][] polys) {
        GameWindow frame = new GameWindow(polys);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class GameWindow extends JFrame {   
    public GameWindow(Point[][] polys) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MapPanel panel = new MapPanel(polys);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setPreferredSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
        add(panel);
        pack();
    }
}

class MapPanel extends JPanel { 
    public MapPanel(Point[][] polys) {
        setLayout(null);
        for (Point[] poly : polys) {
            CountryPolygon boundaries = new CountryPolygon(poly);
            add(boundaries);
        }
        setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(getBounds().width, getBounds().height);
    }
}

class CountryPolygon extends JComponent {
    private Path2D.Double CountryBounds;

    public CountryPolygon(Point[] points) {
        CountryBounds = GetBoundaries(points);
        setBounds(CountryBounds.getBounds());
    }

    private Path2D.Double GetBoundaries(Point[] points) {       
        Path2D.Double bounds = new Path2D.Double();
        bounds.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
        for(Point p : points) {
            if(p == points[0]) continue;
            bounds.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
        }
        bounds.closePath();

        return bounds;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2.setColor(new Color(175, 100, 175));
        g2.fill(CountryBounds);
        g2.dispose();
    }

}
```

My real code is not quite like this, but the problem is very much the same. You may be wondering why I'm not using a layout manager. Well, I'm trying to create a RISK-like game, so I'm having lots of irregular shapes that must all be in the correct place.

I'm quite new to Java, and I couldn't find a single similar problem by googling.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You custom painting is done in the CountryPolygon class. Since you are using a null layout the default size of these components is (0, 0), so the painting of your polygons is done outside the bounds of the class and there is nothing to see.

You need to set the size of each of these components.

Not sure, but maybe you can use the approach found in [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The `DrawOnComponent` example keeps an ArrayList of Rectangles to draw. In your case you can change this to use to hold `Shape` objects and then use the `fillShape(...)` method of Graphics2D to do the painting.

Edit:

The width/height of (30, 30) would still be wrong

```
Point[] poly2 = new Point[] { new Point(50, 10), new Point(80, 10), new Point(80, 40), new Point(50, 40) };
```

You are using points like (80, 10) which is well outside the (30, 30) size. You really need to make the size of each component the size of the parent panel.

Comment: This is incorrect: I'm calling setBounds() inside my CountryPolygon class, which sets both the size of the component and the location of the component. To verify this I called System.out.println(getSize()) from inside the class and System.out.println(boundaries.getSize()) from the for loop inside the MapPanel class. Both returned width=30 height=30 for all of the created components, which is correct.

Comment: Resizing all the objects to 800x600 makes all the components visible as intended. However, I don't understand this. If my jpanel's size is 800x600, and my code makes, for example, poly1's size 30x30 and location x=10 y=10, then why is the component outside of bounds?

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja, the location is irrelevant from a painting perspective. The painting methods paint relative to the component, not the components location. So if you want to paint a point at (80, 50) then the size must be at least (80, 50). Check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). You could use the `ShapeComponent`. This class will translate the x/y offsets back to (0, 0), so that the location will now control the position of the component and its painting. This is important if you ever do "click detection" of your components.